# C# if statement to test if value is not a number

Tags: c#, winforms

I am trying to save the .text of a label to a database but sometimes that label is an infinity symbol. To catch for this I have created an if statement which checks if the label is a number or not and throws a message box up to tell the user. However more often than not the label will be a decimal number and the if statement throws up the message box. I was wondering if anyone could help me out please?

```
private void btnSaveResults_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    btnClearData.Enabled = true;


    if (System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch(lblAerobicCap.Text, "[^0-9]"))
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Im sorry, there seems to have been an error in the inputting of the readings, please restart the test");

    }


    else
    {
        AthletesDetailsNew users = new AthletesDetailsNew();

        DateTime dateTimeVariable = DateTime.Now;

        users.Date_Of_Test = dateTimeVariable;
        users.First_Name = comboBoxFirstName.Text;
        users.Surname = comboBoxNewSurname.Text;
        users.Age = int.Parse(comboBoxAge.Text);
        users.Account_Number = int.Parse(comboBoxAccountNumber.Text);
        users.Aerobic_Capacity = /*Math.Truncate*/(decimal.Parse(lblAerobicCap.Text));


        DataClassDataContext dbCtx = new DataClassDataContext();

        dbCtx.AthletesDetailsNews.InsertOnSubmit(users);

        try
        {
            dbCtx.SubmitChanges();
            MessageBox.Show("Data saved");
        }

        catch
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Data failed to save");

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Try using `double.TryParse()`

Comment: Or `decimal.TryParse`. Types that have a `Parse` method also have a `TryParse`

Comment: Note that the OP is already checking if the value is a number, so the issue does not seem to be on `double.Parse()`.

Comment: Thank you all for you help its worked, really pleased:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `decimal.TryParse` so in case of success you can reuse the result

```
decimal aerobicCap = -1;
if (!decimal.TryParse( lblAerobicCap.Text, out aerobicCap))
{
    MessageBox.Show("Im sorry, there seems to have been an error in the inputting of the readings, please restart the test");
}
else
{
   // code ...
   users.Aerobic_Capacity = aerobicCap;
```

Comment: Thank you very much its really helped me out :)

Answer (score 3):

You should use the `.TryParse()` method for this.

for example:

```
decimal value;
bool isNumber = Decimal.TryParse(inputVariable, out value);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to trim the spaces from `lblAerobicCap.Text` prior to checking if the value is a number.  Something like `lblAerobicCap.Text = lblAerobicCap.Text.Trim()`.

```
lblAerobicCap.Text = lblAerobicCap.Text.Trim();

if (System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch(lblAerobicCap.Text, "[^0-9]"))
{
    MessageBox.Show("Im sorry, there seems to have been an error in the inputting of the readings, please restart the test");

}
[ ... ]
```

Comment: Thank you all very much for your help, its working now :)

Answer (score 0):

Better still avoid users entering anything but numbers. That way you do not have to validate the input.

For the digits use something like this:

```
void Control_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    if (!Char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar))
    {
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

Decimal:

```
void Control_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode != Keys.Decimal)
    {
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have used an extension method in the past which works nicely for me:

```
public static bool IsNumber(this object value)
{
    return value is sbyte
           || value is byte
           || value is short
           || value is ushort
           || value is int
           || value is uint
           || value is long
           || value is ulong
           || value is float
           || value is double
           || value is decimal;
}

object testObject = 0.1;
if (testObject.IsNumber()) { MessageBox.Show("Hooray!"); }
```